# Cannot convert value of type Int to expected Argument type '...'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I was trying to understand how parameters work in Swift and thus wrote a simple class as follows

```
class NumberIncreaser {


func numberIncrementor(var number:Int)->Int{
    number += 1
    return number
}


var anotherNumber = numberIncrementor(3)



}
```

However even after explicitly mentioning that the method 'numberIncrementor' takes an Int , Xcode asks for a numberIncreaser object(hope I am using the correct terminology , new to programming) instead. I noticed that when I remove the class the method works perfectly fine. I would like to know why this is so and how can I resolve it.

Thanks!

Comment: You problem is in performing code in scope of `class`. You need to do that in scope of `methods` or `global` scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't compile. Consider this:

```
class NumberIncreaser {

    static func numberIncrementor(var number:Int)->Int{
        number += 1
        return number
    }

}

var anotherNumber = NumberIncreaser.numberIncrementor(3)
```

Or one another variant:

```
class Number {

    var number: Int

    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }

    func increasedNumber() -> Int {
        return number + 1
    }
}

var anotherNumber = Number(number: 3).increasedNumber()
```

Comment: This would definitely work. But, how would you do it if the condition is that another number has to be initialized inside the class?

Comment: @AkshanshThakur Consider the second variant. Does it answer to you question?

Comment: Wait, i understood. Good job, I'll spend some time on it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Impressive. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't use var in func parameter declarations:

```
class NumberIncreaser {
    static func numberIncrementor(number: Int) -> Int {
        let answer = number + 1
        return answer
    }
}

var anotherNumber = NumberIncreaser.numberIncrementor(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` parameters have been deprecated thus number is a constant which makes it immutable. You also cannot call `numberIncrementor` because it's an instance method.

A way out would be to make `numberIncrementor` a class or static method by prefixing the declaration with `class` or `static` keyword: `class func numberIncrementor` and you call it like so: `NumberIncreaser.numberIncrementor(3)`.

```
class NumberIncreaser {

  class func numberIncrementor(number: Int) -> Int {
    return number + 1
  }


  var anotherNumber = NumberIncreaser.numberIncrementor(3)

}
```

Another way would be to make `anotherNumber` a lazy property like so:

```
class NumberIncreaser {

  func numberIncrementor(number: Int) -> Int {
    return number + 1
  }


  lazy var anotherNumber: Int = self.numberIncrementor(3)

}
```